# format moment JS date substracts one day

Tags: javascript, angular, date, momentjs

I am currently using moment.js and I am facing a problem to format a date to *DD MMM* as it's giving me one day less that the original date. I am making the transformation with the next line:

```
moment(date).format('DD MMM')
```

As an example, date is *2019-09-12T00:00:00Z* and for this date, moment is giving me: *11 sept*

Then, why 11 and not 12? is this related with the fact that the hour is 00:00:00Z ? In that case, how should be threated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is almost surely because it is formatting the date in your current time zone, but the original time is expressed in UTC — the `Z` at the end means "zero time zone offset from UTC". For reference, a date with a time zone would, instead of `Z` have something like `-06:00` at the end.

I believe you can solve your issue by using the `moment.utc` method, which causes prints of that date to be printed in UTC rather than your local timezone.

Compare printing the date (with timezone included) without the `.utc`: (my timezone is UTC -6)

```
console.log(moment('2019-09-12T00:00:00Z').format('DD MMM Z'));
=> 11 Sep -06:00
```

vs with `.utc`:

```
console.log(moment.utc('2019-09-12T00:00:00Z').format('DD MMM Z'));
=> 12 Sep +00:00
```